# Factory reset (Software repair) Sony Xperia XCompact (and all other Xperia smartphones) that have software issues like a boot loop

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, sony-xperia

I'd like to share how you can reset your Xperia even if it doesn't boot (start) anymore! It not only helps to break a boot loop, it also helps to unlock the phone if you forgot your smartphone lock credentials. Of course, your data on the phone will be erased.

I will answer my question right away which is allowed by stack exchange rules (at least it used to be)

Answer (score 1):

Sony has gotten really good with their software suppport for their Xperia line up. Their software actually works to get bricked phones alive again.

The method I describe below doesn't require an unlocked bootloader and doesn't unlock it as well. Which is a good thing since you keep your warranty and you won't loose DRM rights that are for example used for the noise reduction software of your Xperia camera.

1. Your phone should be charged at least 80%.
2. Keep your smartphone turned off and disconnected until I say so! Otherwise it won't work.
3. Get the Xperia Companion: https://support.sonymobile.com/de/xperia-companion/
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]
9. Now you can connect your smartphone to your computer while pressing volume down: [image]
10. [image]
11. [image]
12. [image]